# Using Vectors in Java ? (Specifically constructors)

Tags: java, vector

I'm fairly certain I didn't create the constructors correctly. The fact that I'm working with Vectors (not by choice) is confusing to me. Have I done this right? Is there a deep copy method for Vectors?

Thank you for any help.

```
import java.util.Vector; 
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ListVectorBased<E> implements ListInterface<E>, Iterable<E> {

    /** array on which the list is based */
    private Vector<E> items;    

    /** default Constructor */
    public ListVectorBased() {      
    }

    /** constructor with the first item: constructs a list with the
     * specified item as single element of this list
     * @param item first element of the list
     */
    public ListVectorBased(E elt) {
        items.add(1, elt);
    }

    /** copy constructor: create a duplicate of the specified list
     * @param list to be copied
     */
    public ListVectorBased(Vector<E> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }


    /** Tests if this list has no elements.
     * @return <code>true</codeif this list has no elements;
     * <code>false</codeotherwise.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return items.isEmpty();
    } // end isEmpty


    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in this list.
     * @return the number of elements in this list.
     */
    public int size() {
        return items.size();
    }  // end size

    /**
     * Remove all the elements in this list.
     */
    public void removeAll() {
        items.removeAllElements();
    } // end removeAll


    /**
     * Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this
     * list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any)
     * and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their
     * indices).
     * @param index index at which the specified element is to be
     * inserted.
     * @param item element to be inserted.
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException - if index is out of range
     * (index < 0 || index size()).
     */
    public void add(int index, E item) throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (index >= 1 && index <= items.size()+1) {
            items.add(index-1,item);
        } else {  // index out of range
            throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException("ListIndexOutOfBoundsException on add");
        }  // end if
    } //end add


    /**
     * appends the specified element to the end of this list.
     * @param elt element to be added at the end of the list
     */
    public void append(E elt) {
        add (items.size()+1, elt);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
     * @param index index of element to return.
     * @return the element at the specified position in this list.
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException - if index is out of range
     * (index < 0 || index size()).
     */
    public E get(int index)     throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException {  
        if (index >= 1 && index <= items.size()) {
            return items.get(index-1);
        } else {  // index out of range
            throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException(
                            "ListIndexOutOfBoundsException on get");    
        }  // end if
    } // end get


    /**
     * Removes the element at the specified position in this
     * list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one
     * from their indices).
     * @param index the index of the element to remove
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException - if index is out of range
     * (index < 0 || index size()).
     */
    public void remove(int index) throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (index >= 1 && index <= items.size()) {
            // delete item by shifting all items at 
            // positions index toward the beginning of the list
            // (no shift if index == size)
            items.remove(index-1);
        } else {  // index out of range
            throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException(
                            "ListIndexOutOfBoundsException on remove");
        }  // end if
    } //end remove


    /**  delete
     * delete the the specified element in this list if exists. Shifts
     * any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their
     * indices).
     * @param elt the element, if it exists, to delete
     */
    public void delete (E elt) {
        if (items.contains(elt)) {
            items.remove(elt);
        }
    }

    /** contains
     * Looks for the index of the specified element in this list. If
     * the element is not present, the method returns <code>-1</code>
     * @param elt the element which index is looked for.
     * @return either the index of the location in the list where the
     * argument is present or <code>-1</codeif the argument is not
     * contained in the list.
     */
    public int contains(E elt) {
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= items.size(); idx++) {
            if (items.get(idx).equals(elt))
                return idx;
            else
                return -1;
        } // end for
    } //end contains


    /** display
     * Prints all the elements in this list on the console in sequence
     */
    public void display() {
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= items.size(); idx++) {
            System.out.print(items.get(idx));
        } //end for
    } //end display



    /** method to make the class iterable */

    public Iterator<E> iterator(){
        return items.iterator();
    }

}  // end ListVectorBased
```

Comment: `contains` should return `boolean`. If you want a method to return the index of the chosen element use another name, because this name is by convention used for returning `boolean`, choose a name like `indexOf` or something in that style.

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, not quote formatting. I've edited your question and fixed this, but the help section for the SO editor is pretty useful, and you might want to give it a look.

Comment: There is no totally general way to deep copy anything in Java.  The closest thing is to serialize and deserialize, if your elements are `Serializable`, but that's as close as you can get.  If you need a deep copy, you should generally write it by hand using the specific types you need to copy.

Comment: @user2943834 Why removed *[...] my main question [...]* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem I see is that some constructors initialize `items` and others don't, but other code assumes items is non-null. My advice is to make items `final`, always create a new vector, and then copy any items passed in via the constructor to your new private vector, as needed.

(notice that, currently, in the constructor where you take a vector as an argument, you are simply copying the reference to the vector, which means that, unbeknownst to you, some external code might be messing with your "private" vector at any time. That way lies madness…)

i.e.:

```
/** array on which the list is based */
private final Vector<E> items=new Vector<E>();    

/** default Constructor */
public ListVectorBased() {      
}

/** constructor with the first item: constructs a list with the
 * specified item as single element of this list
 * @param item first element of the list
 */
public ListVectorBased(E elt) {
    items.add(elt);
}

/** copy constructor: create a duplicate of the specified list
 * @param list to be copied
 */
public ListVectorBased(Vector<E> items) {
    this.items.addAll(items);
}
```

Comment: @user2943834 note that I just fixed a bug in the single-element constructor. Should just call `items.add(item)`, not `items.add(1,item)` (and if you must use the two-argument add, the first item should be added at index 0, not 1)